# 3D models for steampunk components

Tags: worldbuilding-resources, steampunk

I'm looking to do design/fabrication of some steampunk accessories.   I want to find component-level models of stuff like gears, pistons, gauges, etc.   Can anyone point me to resources?

I've done some online searching, and found free models for [simple components like this one](https://cad.onshape.com/documents/5903e6b0f014052accf93088/w/8698aaf55c2d0de550957007/e/38890e749c6882a851f17eec).  I'm looking for a broader set of components that have matching style.

True 3D CAD formats preferred.   An STL file is hard for me to extend before printing.

Comment: Is this a 'World Building' question or an Arts-and-Crafts question?

Comment: I've added the tag [tag:worldbuilding-resources] for clarity.

Comment: I'm leaning towards closing as off-topic : If it was about worldbuilding, I don't think 3D models with a specific format would have been needed. Pictures for inspiration, or diagrams to look deeper into how it works should be largely enough for that. After all, the world can exist without them, as 3D models are just a representation of it :) ! You should explain why you need so much to print the files instead of just taking notes from the software you use to see them. If you have a good, worldbuilding reason to this, then your question is on-topic.

Comment: I lean to keep it open. Do not forget the goal of wb - "Worldbuilding Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for writers, artists and others using science, geography and culture to _construct_ imaginary worlds and settings.  ... With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to _every question about worldbuilding._" - I think answer to the q fills the bill and has reuse value for other authors to make this OP and their works to be of a better quality. Unfortunatly though there is no good answer as of yet. Look at grabcad place for models as well.

Answer (score 1):

Simple gears and pistons sound like the type of resource you could do online on a simple modeling software yourself. Gears are cylinders with every other side face extruded outward. Pistons are cylinders with a part of the cylinder having slightly smaller diameter.

These are all objects you could make on sites like [TinkerCad](https://www.tinkercad.com/), with rudimentary knowledge of modeling and 10-30 minutes of your time.

Comment: You can make quickly gears indeed; made some myself with Blender. But in order to make them the hottest topic on the steam pipe market :p... Might need a little more skills.

Comment: Yes, thanks.   I use OnShape, and they have an featurescript for building engineering-quality gear models with little effort, but of course, they lack some of the stylistic elements.